# What is the type of error called where you didn't consider correlation

Tags: probability, error

What is this type of error called?

Example - 
Gene A is prevalent in 45% of the population. 
Gene B is prevalent in 60% of the population.

They would be predicted to be found together in (0.45 x 0.60) 27% of the population. However, they are actually found together in the population 50% of the time because they are strongly *linked*.

Is linked the right word? Correlated? And what is it called when you did not account for that and your initial hypothesis was that you could predict their frequencies because you thought they were independent. Does that have a name in statistics?

Comment: I would consider the word "dependent" (dependency), since there can be dependence while at the same time the (Pearson) correlation is zero. I don't know if there is a specific word for assuming independence while it is not a valid assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Being rigorous for a moment, two variables can bu dependent yet uncorrelated. There are a few examples for this case, but they are really constructed especially for that.

Once you show that $P(A,B)\neq P(A)P(B)$, the variables can no longer be considered independent so you can claim they are dependent. In most cases this will also imply they are correlated (but once again these are some rare cases).